# Asp.net MVC partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rss

I want to show news on my main page using Rss Feeds. I want to show news somewhere in side panel. How i will use PartialViews  to show it?

```
    public ActionResult Feed()
    {
        string feedUrl = "http://www.gadgetfind.com/rss.xml";
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUrl);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);            


        return View(feed);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 2 you can use `RenderAction`:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Feed", "MyController"); %>
```

Phil Haack wrote a nice [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) about this topic.

Comment: <% Html.RenderAction("Feed", "MyController"); %>